# WiX - Prevent downgrade with check for revision

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am searching a way to prevent a downgrade of my application. But the "problem" is, that I have to check the revision-number

for example:
it should be possible to install 1.0.0.2 when 1.0.0.1 is installed - but it should not be possible to install 1.0.0.1 when 1.0.0.2 is installed.

I know, that the Element MajorUpgrade only check the first three tokens. 
Perhaps someone can give me an idea, how to do this? Can I wrote a CustomAction to do this? - When yes, how can I check in the CustomAction which version should be installed and which version is installed?
Where does I have to call the CustomAction and how can I show a message and prevent installing from the CustomAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common requirement. The following pattern frequently used:

```
<Upgrade Id="THE-PRODUCT-GUID">
  <UpgradeVersion Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONINSTALLED" Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.packageVersion)"
          IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" MigrateFeatures="yes" />
          IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="yes" />
  <UpgradeVersion Property="NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED" Minimum="$(var.packageVersion)" Maximum="99.0.0.0"
          IncludeMinimum="no" IncludeMaximum="yes" />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED&lt;&gt;"" AND NOT Installed</Custom>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize">PREVIOUSVERSIONINSTALLED&lt;&gt;""</RemoveExistingProducts>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

`PreventDowngrading` custom action is essentially a breaking error:

```
<CustomAction Id="PreventDowngrading" Error="Newer version already installed." />
```

Comment: I did the same thing  @KMoraz.
but it is not working in my case...

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/checking-for-oldies) tutorial on WIX website worked for me.

Summarizing it you have to add UpgradeVersion tag in Upgrade tag which should be in your Product. Then add a custom action and conditionally schedule it - before FindRelatedProducts and testing if a newer version is already installed.

The code could be something like:

```
<Product ...>
 <Upgrade Id="YOUR-UPGRADE_GUID">  
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERFOUND" Minimum="{CURRENTVERSION}}" IncludeMinimum="no" />
 </Upgrade>
 <CustomAction Id="NoDowngrade" Error="Error Message" />
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="NoDowngrade" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERFOUND</Custom>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Product>
```

Replace CURRENTVERSION with the version number of your product.